# OSX packageMaker need to close all browsers during install

Tags: macos, packagemaker

I am developing a browser plugin which I want to package and distribute. I would like to       know how can I prompt a user to close all browsers during installation. I want to use       PackageMaker for creating the installer.

Is there a better alternative ?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous poster, forcing the browser to close will get you Adobe/Microsoft like hate from your users, including me.

But you can do it with the [must-close](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/DistributionDefinitionRef/Chapters/Distribution_XML_Ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005370-CH100-SW77) tag in the `Distribution.xml`:

```
<!-- Lion and above App Closing -->
<pkg-ref id="com.company.pkg.SomeBrowerPlugin">
    <must-close>
        <app id="com.apple.Safari"/>
    </must-close>
</pkg-ref>
```

More details on package generation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode4-developer-id-mountain-lion-re/11487658#11487658).

Answer (score 0):

Making users to quit browsers is futile, in my point of view. Many non-browser programs use webview (OS X's standard view showing html), which might be loading your plugin.

It would be easier to set your package so that it requires re-login or re-boot of the computer.

Comment: If the user quits(not close) the browser, the plugin works. Otherwise the plugin is not loaded.